# CoreData predicate latest stored date

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I need to get the latest date from coredata

i found a way

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
```

so sort them by date and then pick the first

**however can this not be done more optimal? this approach looks like a brute force**

sort is nlogn, but simple search for the max is n

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually ask SQL for just that value, not the object with that value:

```
NSExpression *date = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *maxDate = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
    arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:maxDate]];
NSExpressionDescription *d = [[[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init] autorelease];
[d setName:@"maxDate"];
[d setExpression:maxSalaryExpression];
[d setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:d]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
} else {
    if (0 < [objects count]) {
        NSLog(@"Maximum date: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxDate"]);
    }
}
```

This is described in more detail under **Fetching Managed Objects** -> **Fetching Specific Values** in the CoreData documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On line 2 maxDate expression refers to itself (maxDate).
I assume this must be the "date" variable from the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's pretty much the best way. I'm not sure whether there is a more efficient way since it has to compare every date anyway to figure out which the oldest is. 
Here are 2 other ways:

1) You could work with BOOLs as an attribute of the managed object. (like oldest = 1)
However, you'd have to find a new "oldest" managed object every time you delete one.

2) You could just save the oldest one until it changes. This might save a lot of work if you have to find the oldest managedObject often.

It depends on your application (how many times you insert/remove managed objects and how many times you need the oldest object).